# managing state in react with dynamically generated form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, radio-button

I have a component that fetches a json list of questions from an api. Then there's 5 radio buttons for every question for answering (from "strongly disagree" to "strongly agree").

The questions are fetched in componentDidMount(), stored in this.state.questions, and mapped to questionComponents in render(). The components (and radio buttons) are identified by key.

I need to store the answers as an array in the state. This obviously has to happen in handleChange, but I've no idea how to do this. I'm pretty new to react so there's probably an easier way to do this than what I'm doing now.

Here's App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Question from './Question';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      answers: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value, type, checked, key} = event.target
    this.setState(prevState => {
      // 
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:7777/api/questions")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>  {

        this.setState({
          questions: data
        })

      })
  }
  render () {
    const questionComponents = this.state.questions.map(question =>
     <Question key={question.id} question={question.question} handleChange = {this.handleChange} />)

    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Questions!</h1>
        {questionComponents}
      </div>
    )
  }

}
export default App;
```

And Question.js

```
import React from "react"

function Question(props) {
  return (
    <div className="question">
      <p>{props.question}</p>
      <label>strongly disagree</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name={props.key}
        key={props.key}
        value="1"
        onChange={props.handleChange}>
        </input>
        <label> disagree</label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name={props.key}
          key={props.key}
          value="2"
          onChange={props.handleChange}>
        </input>

        <label>no opinion</label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name={props.key}
          key={props.key}
          value="3"
          onChange={props.handleChange}>
        </input>

        <label> agree</label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name={props.key}
            key={props.key}
            value="4"
            onChange={props.handleChange}>
          </input>

          <label>strongly agree</label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name={props.key}
              key={props.key}
              value="5"
              onChange={props.handleChange}>
            </input>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Question
```

Comment: Can you provid a sample json?
The line of the server is probably local..

Comment: ```
[
  {
    "id": 48,
    "question": "is this a sample question?"
  },
  {
    "id": 50,
    "question": "what about this?"
  },
```

I actually got this figured out after I posted the question. My problem was that I was trying to use the key attribute to identify the questions, when I actually had to send the id to the question component and use it as name, after which it was easy to get it from event.target.name and save it to state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example for you:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      questions: [
        {
          id: '123',
          question: 'What?'
        },
        {
          id: '1234',
          question: 'When?'
        }
      ],
      answers: {}
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => { // using an arrow function instead of binding in the constructor
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    // this will add / update a key-value pair depending if it exists or not
    this.setState(state => state.answers[name] = value)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // import your data
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.answers)
    const { questions } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Questions</h3>
        {questions.map(question => {
          return <Question key={question.id} name={question.id} question={question.question} handleChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Question(props) {
  // create a label array to loop over instead of typing all input fields
  const labels = ['strongly disagree', 'disagree', 'no opinion', 'agree', 'strongly agree'] 
  return (
    <div className="question">
      <p>{props.question}</p>
      <div className="inputs">
          {labels.map((label, idx) => {
             return (
               <div key={props.name}>
                  <label key={label}>{label}</label>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name={props.name}
                    value={idx + 1}
                    onChange={event => props.handleChange(event)}
                  />
               </div>
             )
          })}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The answers are stored in an object instead of an array as it's easier to manage. You can also use an array but updating it is a bit more difficult as you have to loop over all items to find the one you want to update.
I didn't know what your question object looks like so I improvised. 
Note that the `key` attribute is used by React to identify elements returned from a `map` function. Don't use it otherwise.

I hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i  actually got it figured out last night. My problem was trying to use the key attribute, but passing the id and using that as a name was the solution.